# Prove that $\Pr\left(A_n\right)=1 \implies \Pr\left(\bigcap_n A_n\right)=1$

Tags: probability

[image]

From the problem above, I intend to prove. In my opinion, I think that I should take the intersection with the limit outside the probability so that we are left with the initial part of $P(A$n$)$ $=1$. Is this a correct assertion?

Comment: You need $A_n$ to be a monotonic family of sets, i.e. $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ or the other way around to pull out the intersection. Normally this isn't the case. But can you rewrite $\cap_n A_n$ as $\cap_n B_n$ where $B_n$ is monotonic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easier than you think. We have $\Pr(A_n)=1$ which means that $\Pr(A_n^c)=1-\Pr(A_n)=0$, for all $n \geq 1$. Recall that for probability measures we have countable sub-additivity (also referred to as [Boole's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality)), i.e.

$$\Pr\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Pr(B_n)$$

for any (measurable) events $B_1, B_2, \ldots $. Therefore, by De Morgan's law, we have

$$\Pr\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right) = 1-\Pr\left( \bigcup_{n}^{\infty} A_n^{c} \right) \geq 1- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Pr \left( A_n^c\right) = 1$$

and that does it.